# "ANY Command denied for user" with View-over-View DDL via JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc, view

I'm having a pretty weird issue here. We're using Pentaho Kettle to manage the schema of our database (which in turn uses the MySQL JDBC mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar). When trying to create a view which includes another view (interfaces in this case), we get:

```
2012/06/26 11:46:55 - SQL2 - ERROR : Couldn't execute SQL: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `test_delete2` as select  * from interfaces
2012/06/26 11:46:55 - SQL2 - ERROR : ANY command denied to user 'ncim'@'xxx.xxx.xxx..xx' for table '/var/mysql/mysql2018/tmp/#sql_4e67_0'
```

However, using the same statement and user, but via the mysql command line client, works as expected. Also, creating views with JDBC over ordinary tables works as well.

This is with MariaDB 5.2.10 on Solaris 10 on the server side, but we're having the same issue with Oracle MySQL too.

Any good ideas what could cause this?

PS: I'm aware that creating views over views isn't the best idea ever, but assume for the moment that it can't be avoided in this case.

Comment: Try to run SHOW GRANTS using JDBC. What is the result?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any good that this should show something else than when not using JDBC (and there the user definitively has the rights), but who knows, I'll give it a try. May take some days though until I have access to this environment the next time.

Comment: Add the result of the SHOW GRANTS to the question.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue over Mysqli in php creating a view using other views. It makes sense for me.

Comment: Sorry no good news for you, we just worked around it by invoking the mysql command line client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that issuing the `use database` [statement](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-select-database/) before creating the view solved my problem. This seems to be related to a MySql bug report [Bug #91122](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91122) "Failed to create a view containing a from subquery(No selected database)"

Basically if you try to create a view with the `dbname.view_name` syntax then the error can appear. However, if you issue the `use database` statement beforehand, then everything is good.

Comment: Excellent, so maybe after eight years the mystery is solved! I can't really try it anymore but I'm willing to accept this as the answer instead. Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm that I just had this error (literally Aug 2020), and this fixed it, running in RDS Amazon Aurora MySQL 5.7. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can also confirm Mysql Version 8.0.23 with C++ connector.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a very similar problem here.
Given that you've already checked your grants, try explicitly setting the Database in use before creating the view.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was due to create of VIEW where some of the columns were from another database which was missing on the target instance. It seems that if you do not have the right permissions also will come to this "meaningful" error "ANY command denied to user ...."

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we never found a solution for this, so we just went with the workaround of calling an external sql script executed in the mysql client.

Not sure if it's still an issue in current Mysql, in the meantime we migrated to a different database and also I don't even work in this team anymore.

Just mentioning this here since it seems to still be an often viewed question.

Answer (score 1):

`use database` query before creating the view works absolute charm as answered by Steve Mc. I was stuck on this for weeks!

Comment: Add comment to the correct answer instead of adding an answer here.

Comment: Apologies and thank you for the tip but I need to have 50 reputation before I can comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think your GRANT permissions have flaws in it.

When using JDBC to access the database remotely you need to create Grant permissions for the user machines as-well.

Do you have a GRANT as follows? If not try granting like the following:

```
grant all on <database>.* to ‘< username >’@'%' identified by '< passwd >';
```